# Output a 15 digit number

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I have a program that is suppose to find the sum of all the numbers between 1 and 75 in the fibonacci sequence that are divisible by three and add them together. I got the program working properly the only problem I am having is being able to display such a large number. I am told that the answer should be 15 digits. I have tried long long, long double, unsigned long long int and none of those produce the right output (they produce a negative number).

code:

```
 long fibNum(int kth, int nth);

int main()
{
    int kTerm;
    int nTerm;

    kTerm = 76;
    nTerm = 3;

    std::cout << fibNum(kTerm, nTerm) << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

long fibNum(int kth, int nth)
{
    int term[100];
    long firstTerm;
    long secondTerm;
    long exactValue;

    int i;

    term[1] = 1;
    term[2] = 1;
    exactValue = 0;

    do
    {
        firstTerm = term[nth - 1];
        secondTerm = term[nth - 2];
        term[nth] = (firstTerm + secondTerm);

        nth++;
    }
    while(nth < kth);

    for(i = 1; i < kth; i++)
    {
        if(term[i] % 3 == 0)
        {
            term[i] = term[i];
        }
        else
            term[i] = 0;

        exactValue = term[i] + exactValue;
    }

    return exactValue;
```

I found out that the problem has to do with the array. The array cannot store the 47th term which is 10 digits. Now I have no idea what to do

Comment: It's hard to tell without something that compiles as is, but [looks like a 15-digit number to me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/217c60a765f54a33).

Comment: @chris: Oops! I read factorial, not fibonacci.

Comment: Try declaring `term`, `firstTerm`, `secondTerm`, and `exactValue` as `double`. About the output, it depends on what you use to output stuff. But, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/) is how you manipulate `iostream`, and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) is how it works for `printf`.

Comment: As a side note, I'm not sure why everything's a `long long` except for `secondTerm`.

Comment: `long long` is more than wide enough to support 15-digit integers. Forget about using `long double` or any other floating-point type; you'll gain range at the expense of lost precision, which means you won't be able to detect multiples of 3. And I've removed the "large-data" tag; the term refers to multi-terabyte data sets, not to integers that can fit in 64 bits.

Comment: @Lemming: Floating-point is inexact; for sufficiently large values, it will be impossible to detect multiples of 3. `long long` is wide enough.

Comment: @KeithThompson Fair enough, I got the impression that it was an overflow issue. But, as that's not the case `long long` is better.

Comment: You've included no code that attempts to "display" or "output" anything, which is the question you've asked ("Output a 15-digit number" and "If I can't display the entire number how can I display it in scientific notation?"). If you're not showing us how you're trying to display or output it, it's difficult to say why it's not working.

Comment: So where do you try to output it?

Answer (score 1):

Type `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits (and is exactly 64 bits on every implementation I've seen). Its maximum value, `LLONG_MAX` is at least 2<sup>63</sup>-1, or `9223372036854775807`, which is 19 decimal digits -- so `long long`is more than big enough to represent 15-digit numbers.

Just use type `long long` consistently. In your code, you have one variable of type `long double`, which has far more range than `long long` but may have less precision (which could make it impossible to determine whether a given number is a multiple of 3.)

You could also use `unsigned long long`, whose upper bound is at least 2<sup>64</sup>-1, but either `long long` or `unsigned long long` should be more than wide enough for your purposes.

Displaying a `long long` value in C++ is straightforward:

```
long long num = some_value;
std::cout << "num = " << num << "\n";
```

Or if you prefer `printf` for some reason, use the `"%lld"` format for `long long`, `"%llu"` for `unsigned long long`.

(For integers too wide to fit in 64 bits, there are software packages that handle arbitrarily large integers; the most prominent is GNU's [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). But you don't need it for 15-digit integers.)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is take `char s[15]`and `int i=14,k`,
and then go for while loop till `sum!=0`
Under while body

```
k=n%10;
s[i]=k+48;
n=n/10;
i--;
```

Comment: Why do you just hint at a conversion from integer to ASCII, and why don't you address the real problem here?

Comment: The real problem is to get output of very large number. So I did bu taking th string and scaning each integer by it's ASCII Value. Jut read the Question asked.

Answer (score 0):

> The array cannot store the 47th term which is 10 digits.

This indicates that your architecture has a type `long` with just 32 bits. That is common for 32-bit architecture. 32 bits cover 9 digit numbers and low 10-digit numbers, to be precise 2.147.483.647 for `long` and 4.294.967.295 for `unsigned long`.

Just change your `long` types to `long long` or `unsigned long long`, including the return type of `fibNum`. That would easily cover 18 digits.